# LINQ How to search data from large XML file?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an xml file with about 500 mb and i'm using LINQ with c# to query that file, but it's very slow, because it loads everything into memory. Is there anyway that i can query that file without loading all into memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xmlteam/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2) should get you up and running. Take a look at the `SimpleStreamAxis` method, which is very handy for finding nodes in large XML files. I've successfully used a variant of this method on 5GB XML files without loading the file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible when using Linq. Linq loads a model of the full xml into memory so you can have access using the tree structure.
If you want fast access without loading the file into memory you could use XmlReader class.
This class gives you a fast forward-only xml parser that has only the current node in memory.

Here is some help on that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

**Edit:** Sorry, didn't know that its possible to combine xmlreader with linq.

Comment: You can combine an XmlReader with LINQ: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the technique described on MSDN's page about [`XNode.ReadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx) to generate an IEnumerable of `XNode`s (in the example they provide, `XElement`s) from an `XmlReader`.

Note that when you read an `XElement` from a `Stream` or `XmlReader`, the entire contents of that element must be read too - so you'll still need a little bit of custom logic in the IEnumerator logic to ensure that the *right* XElements get returned - for instance, if you return the root element, you might as well just parse the entire document right away since the root element contains almost everthing anyhow.  The [`XNode.ReadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx) example contains such logic too.

Comment: sounds pretty tough.  I'd love to see a sample of that someday.